# Set a Read Only Attribute From Manage Bean In ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

i wish to set my input attribute to read only once the submit button have been clicked. Unfortunately, system can't located where my method was by prompt me this error message 'does not have the property 'validate_submitted''. My code as below

```
 In Manage Bean: 
      public boolean validate_submitted(){
    Number temp = pa_header_row.getSubmitted();
    if (temp != null && temp.intValue() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }       
        return false;        
    }

  In the field: 
     <af:inputDate value="#{bindings.InvoiceDate.inputValue}"
                            label="Invoice Date"
                            shortDesc="#{bindings.InvoiceDate.hints.tooltip}"
                            id="id2"
                            readOnly="#{viewScope.DetailsInvoiceAmountBean.validate_submitted}"> 
                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.InvoiceDate.validator}"/>
                <af:convertDateTime pattern="#{bindings.InvoiceDate.format}"/>
              </af:inputDate>
```

Any suggestion to resolve it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the method `getvalidate_submitted` (in your bean) so that your page is able to pick up the method.

Note that your method name isn't really following the Java naming 'standards'. From the best practice point of view you should name the method `getValidateSubmitted` and use the following EL `#{viewScope.DetailsInvoiceAmountBean.validateSubmitted}`

Comment: Hi i found the way to resolve it already. Because in the ADF the read attribute can't pick up the method. The method in manage bean only available in action listener. Anyway, thxz for ur help.